# Creating Pie Chart in Legend with Varying Representations of Percentage using ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, legend, chart

I want to create a pie chart within a legend in ArcGIS that reflects differences in percentage (ie: male vs female). An example of what I want to create is below.

[image: Sample of pie chart with varying sized sections]

How do I create something like this in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Answer (score 0):

There will not be a single tool/option to construct such a legend but the two ways you could try are:

1. Use graphic elements either interactively or through code
2. Create a point feature class that has fields and values similar to your layer with pie chart symbology so that you can apply the same symbology to them, and then, since it appears that you want the legend to overlap your data frame, just add it as a layer to that data frame and use editing to move the points into the precise position that you want them.

I think the second one would be the easiest to implement and maintain.